# proc mean with weight python equivalent

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sas

I'm converting SAS to python and came across this code where I'm not matching the exact value. SAS says to take the weighted mean of the associates columns and pwgtp columns. But tried in python value not matching.

```
proc means data=hhhead1 nway noprint;
 weight pwgtp;
 var associates;
 output out=propassociates (drop=_:) mean=; run;
```

Answer is 0.2871426408 of SAS

I have tried doing various methods to get the weight mean.
Data consist of 1,2 million rows 
Can't share the data sorry

```
propassociates = hhhead1.groupby(by = ['PWGTP_y'])['associates'].mean().reset_index()

np.mean(propassociates['associates'])
```

Answer is 0.26806426594942845

```
hhhead1['weight_sum'] = hhhead1['associates'] * hhhead1['PWGTP_x']
propassociates = hhhead1['weight_sum'].sum() / hhhead1['PWGTP_x'].sum()
```

answer is 0.08837267780237641

```
propassociates = hhhead1.groupby(by = ['PWGTP_y'])['associates'].mean().reset_index()

np.mean(propassociates['associates'])
```

Answer is 0.26806426594942845

```
hhhead1['weight_sum'] = hhhead1['associates'] * hhhead1['PWGTP_x']
propassociates = hhhead1['weight_sum'].sum() / hhhead1['PWGTP_x'].sum()
```

answer is 0.08837267780237641

Answer is 0.2871426408 of SAS

Answer is 0.26806426594942845

Comment: if you can't share data please consider adding alternative data that produces same error

Comment: Run the same code using the sashelp.class data set, that's pretty trivial and can be shared, or sashelp.cars, which I think is similar to mpg.

Answer (score 0):

```
def wavg(group, avg_name, weight_name):
    d = group[avg_name]
    w = group[weight_name]
    try:
        return (d * w).sum() / w.sum()
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return d.mean()
a=data1.groupby(['GroupByVar']).apply(wavg, "yourVar", "WeightVar")
```

This should work